# Set snap raster in GDAL(C#) rasterize functions

Tags: raster, gdal, c#, rasterization, snapping

I want to set snap raster for the function rasterize of GDAL, but I can not found. The options parameters are as the following code (C#). What is wrong?

```
rasterizeOptions = new string[] { "ALL_TOUCHED=TRUE", "ATTRIBUTE=" + fieldName }; //To set all touched pixels into raster pixel  

    Gdal.RasterizeLayer(myDataset, 1, bandlist, layer, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 1, burnValues, rasterizeOptions, new Gdal.GDALProgressFuncDelegate(ProgressFunc), "Raster conversion");
```

This seems to be possible in other tools such as [ArcGIS’s Polygon to Raster] snap raster

Comment: Please explain what "snap raster" should do.

Comment: When I do some operations between rasters, if cells' center is not the same, Then I can assign the center of the output raster.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a try by making an empty copy of the raster to be snapped with gdal_create https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_create.html

```
gdal_create -if prototype.tif output.tif
```

and then rasterize the vectors into this empty template file "output.tif".

Comment: many thanks too, I will try to finish the snap function based on your help. This is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of two ways that raster snapping can be accomplished in QGIS:

1. From the *Raster > Projections > Warp* tool.  With this tool, the input layer is the layer to be adjusted (snapped).  The only options that have to be set are 1) the *Output file resolution in target georeferenced units*, which is set to the snap raster’s pixel size and 2) the *Georeferenced extents of output file to be created”* drop-down, where the snap raster is selected.

You'll notice that this builds a GDAL/OGR console call, visible near the bottom of the tool.  You can copy/paste this text should you wish to utilize a GDAL operation outside of QGIS.

2. Use the *Raster > Align Raster* tool.

These have been previously discussed at: [Specifying snap raster in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316056/specifying-snap-raster-in-qgis)

To help people understand the snap raster concept, ESRI has a nice explanation at https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/how-snap-raster-environment-works.htm  Since links can go stale, here's a screenshot from that web page that provides "a picture is worth a thousand words" view:

[image]

Comment: many thanks, I will try to finish the snap function based on your help.